# How add less than and greater than in data-config file of solr

Tags: solr, solr4

This is how it goes
I have two tables

```
  businessmasters
 Business_id      Business_point
   1                    3.4
   2                    2.8 
   3                    8.0

business_Colors
business_colors_id   business_rating_from     business_rating_to     rating
   1                         2                           5              OK
   2                         5                           10             GOOD
   3                        10                           15             Excellent
```

I want to link the two tables based business_rating_from and business_rating_to like

```
        SELECT business_colors_id,business_rating_from,business_rating_to,rating where      
         business_rating_from >= 2 AND business_rating_to < 5;
```

Now i want to index them into solr.This is how my data-config file looks

```
      <entity name="business_colors" query="SELECT business_colors_id,
 business_rating_from,business_rating_to,business_text,hex_colors,rgb_colors,business_colors_modify
    from business_colors where business_rating_from &gt;= '${businessmasters.business_point}' AND    
    business_rating_to &lt; '${businessmasters.business_point}'"
    deltaQuery="select business_colors_id from business_colors where business_colors_modify >   
   '${dih.last_index_time}'"
    parentDeltaQuery="select business_id from businessmasters where business_point &lt;   
    ${business_colors.business_rating_from} AND business_point &gt;=      
     ${business_colors.business_rating_from}"> 
    <field column="business_colors_id" name="id"/>   
   <field column="business_rating_from" name="business_rating_from" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field column="business_rating_to" name="business_rating_to" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field column="business_text" name="business_text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field column="hex_colors" name="hex_colors" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field column="rgb_colors" name="rgb_colors" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
    <field column="business_colors_modify" name="business_colors_modify" indexed="true"     
     stored="true"/>
```

When i click full indexing data does not get index and no error is shown.
What is wrong with this,Can any one help and advise.
How do i achieve what i want to do
What i have seen is that if i replace AND with OR it works fine.SO why is OR working and AND not working

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your query may not return any record is the case in this one. Since you mention it

> if i replace AND with OR it works fine.SO why is OR working and AND not working